# Get a Dataframe index if it is of a specific dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to build a preprocessing pipeline, but I am struggling a little to generate a list of the indexes for each column that is an object dtype. I have been able to get the names of each into an array using the following code:

```
categorical_features = [col for col in input.columns if input[col].dtype == 'object']
```

Is there an easy way to get the index of these columns, from the original input dataframe into a list, like this one that I built manually?

```
c = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,28,29,
     30,31,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,50,51,55,56]
```

Comment: Just curious - @Tom, why did you accept the answer you did? It's perfectly fine - Umar's answer is great. I'm just a bit curious as to your reasoning :)

Comment: If I could have picked two I would! Thank you for your help, Umar's just flowed with the logic I have used elsewhere. But I hadn't come across .get_indexer before, so will definitely use that again!

Comment: Np :) Yeah, `get_indexer` is one of those crazy functions you'd never learn the purpose of it without being told it explicitly in or experimenting with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `select.dtypes` and `enumerate`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'B' : [1,2,3], 'C' : [1, '2', '3']})

print(df)

   A  B  C
0  A  1  1
1  B  2  2
2  C  3  3

idx_cols = [idx for idx, col in enumerate(df.select_dtypes('object').columns) ]
```

---

```
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) + [`df.columns.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
categorical_features = df.columns.get_indexer(df.select_dtypes('object').columns)
```

- `df.select_dtypes` returns a copy of `df` with only the columns that are of the specified dtype(s) (you can specify multiple, e.g. `df.select_dtypes(['object', 'int'])`).
- `df.columns.get_indexer` returns the indexes of the specified columns.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` can help with that:

```py
categorical_features_indexes = [i for i, col in enumerate(input.columns) if input[col].dtype == 'object']
```